# How to load Excel file into sybase ASE db table?

Tags: excel, loading, sybase

I am trying to load data from Excel sheet to Sybase ASE database table. I tried following ways but facing errors. Please share your thoughts. I created a temporary table #Temp_Table into which I want to load data from file.

INPUT INTO #Temp_Table 
FROM 'C:\Testdata_Tabdelimited.txt' FORMAT TEXT;

Error: Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

I also tried a different query but no luck
LOAD  TABLE #Temp_Table 
FROM 'C:\Testdata_Tabdelimited.txt' FORMAT TEXT;
[Error Code: 156, SQL State: S1000]  Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'TABLE'.

Thanks

Comment: It looks like you are not actually using ASE commands.  Those may be IQ, or SqlAnywhere commands.  `INPUT INTO` and `LOAD TABLE` are not valid ASE commands.

Comment: INPUT INTO and OUTPUT TO only work in the GUI version of iSQL (DBISQL), as best as I can tell. For command line iSQL, there a redirect-like construct for output, “go > filename”, but I’m not finding an equivalent for Input yet. (Long dead thread, but I’m putting this here for anyone that Googles this.)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method it to save the Excel file as a CSV or other character delimited file, and use the BCP utility to import the data into your Temp Table.  You can use tab delimited files, but in my experience, they tend to be risky if there is any user entered data (VARCHAR or TEXT) that could contain tabs.

Documentation: [Using bcp to Transfer Data to and from SAP ASE](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc30191.1600/doc/html/san1367605061117.html)

Comment: Thank you Michael for your thoughts. I refrained myself from using INPUT or LOAD commands. I tried following bcp command but that is not performing any functionality as seen below.                                 4> bcp tempdb..Temp_XXXXX in Testdata_Tabdelimited.txt -UXXXXXX -SXXXX -PXXXXXXXXX -c testload.txt
5>
6>
7>
8> exit

Comment: I am planning write a C program to parse the CSV file and read the data for each record and create SQL script to insert data into table.

Comment: @cppminds Bcp is a seperate utility, and should be executed from the command line, not from within isql.  Please look at the documentation link for information on how to use BCP.